# How can I search multiple arrays and output all duplicates to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a scheduling system and I have several arrays (the exact number varies) which contain minutes of events. I need to end up with a single array which contains only the minutes which at least 2 other arrays contain.

Here's an example of what I need. Given the following arrays:

Array 1:

```
[0] => 500
[1] => 501
[2] => 502
...
[99] => 599
```

Array 2:

```
[0] => 450
[1] => 451
[2] => 452
...
[99] => 549
```

Array 3:

```
[0] => 550
[1] => 551
[2] => 552
...
[99] => 649
```

Array 4:

```
[0] => 650
[1] => 651
[2] => 652
...
[99] => 749
```

I would want to get

Final Array:

```
[0] => 500
[1] => 501
[2] => 502
...
[99] => 599
```

This is because Array 1 and Array 2 overlap from 500 - 549 and Array 3 and Array 1 overlap from 550 to 599. The values in array 4 would be ignored because they're not found in any other array.

Hopefully that makes sense, and any help is appreciated!

Comment: right, and what have you tried?

Comment: Sounds like a [k-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) with the special case that you need to see a minvalue at least 2 times. Have you tried writing anything yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for counting, then take only the keys of count of two or more and sort the values (which might be omitted for new es systems) and get an array with the values back.

```js
var values = [500, 450, 550, 650],
    arrays = values.map(function (a) {
        return Array.apply(null, { length: 100 }).map(function (_, i) {
            return a + i;
        });
    }),
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

arrays.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        hash[b] = (hash[b] || 0) + 1;
    });
});

result = Object
    .keys(hash)
    .filter(function (k) {
        return hash[k] >= 2;
    })
    .map(Number)
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why filter the hash instead of adding values to an array as soon as the hash contains the value? Wouldn’t that eliminate looping over the values one extra time?

Comment: @Thijs, you would need for every update of hash a check, which could be more often, than later to filter the keys.

Comment: Ah, of course! Now I see the error in my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use EcmaScript feature Array.indexOf

```
for(var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i])...// repeat for all tables)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made solution using an object to keep track of the unique values. Only once a value is already in the object does it get added to the result array.

```js
function createArray(startValue, endValue) {
  const
    result = [];
  for(let value = startValue; value <= endValue; value++) {
    result.push(value);
  }
  
  return result;
}

function intersectArrays(values) {
  const
    result = [],
    hash = Object.create(null);
  
  // Loop over all the values.
  values.forEach(value => {
    // When the value is already in the hash it means it occurs in more than 1 
    // of the source arrays and thus it belongs in the intersection. Only 
    // when the value is false should it be added to the result array. This 
    // to make sure the value doesn't get added to the result array 
    // multiple times.
    if (hash[value] === undefined) {
      // Add the value to the hash. Set the value to false to indicate it hasn't
      // been added to result as yet.
      hash[value] = false;    
    } else if (hash[value] === false) {
      result.push(value);
      // Set the value to true, the value has been added to the result.
      hash[value] = true;    
    }
  });

  // Return the array with intersecting values.
  return result;
}

const
  // Create the arrays from the question.
  arrayA = createArray(500, 599),
  arrayB = createArray(450, 549),
  arrayC = createArray(550, 649),
  arrayD = createArray(650, 749),
  // Create an extra array with overlap to test if all values will appear 
  // pnly once in the intersection.
  arrayE = createArray(500, 599),
  // Create the intersection.
  intersection = intersectArrays([...arrayA, ...arrayB, ...arrayC, ...arrayD, ...arrayE, ...arrayE]);
  
// Log the result.
console.log(`Number of items in intersection: ${intersection.length}`);
console.log(intersection);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create two arrays, overlapArray and allArrays.

2) Populate the allArrays with all your existing arrays

3)make sure that allArrays has only unique values:

```
var uniqueAllArrays = Array.from(new Set(allArrays))
```

3) compare each array with your uniqueAllArrays, for each overlap, put that value on overlapArray